# Hotspot identification - FIRMS by NASA

Tags: nasa, hot-spot

I am new to Remote Sensing and Fire Management Resources. [FIRMS](https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/) by NASA gives real time active
fire locations.

There is a tab **Archive Download** > **Download yearly summary by country** > There are csv files of different countries.

Do these files show hotspot areas or do they show all the areas scanned by the satellite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over the documentation on the site, I would say the CSV files are a summary per country of the detected fire hotspots.

The documentation for the MODIS sensor states:

> Each hotspot/active fire detection represents the center of a 1km
> (approx.) pixel flagged as containing one or more fires, or other
> thermal anomalies (such as volcanoes).

So one would then describe the coordinate in the csv as the centroid of the pixel that may have contained a fire.

In the csv there are also Brightness field. Which is the temperature of the pixel in Kelvin

> Channel 21/22 brightness temperature of fire
> pixel.

Sources:

https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov/faq/firms-faq
https://cdn.earthdata.nasa.gov/conduit/upload/10575/MODIS_C6_Fire_User_Guide_B.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are some latitudes and longitudes that are quite near to each other. Take Canada's data, for example. What does this show? Moreover, there are 97101 entries for Canada (modis_2021_Canada). Does it mean, there were this many fire occurances?

Comment: @user14:  The points that are close together may be the same event, but captured on different passes of the sensor. I had a look at the Canada csv, and there are groupings of hotspots, but the points were captured on different days and different tracks. So a possibility is the event was captured at a similar location, just the centroid of the pixel was offset during that second / third pass. could also be the fire event may have moved into the neighboring pixel. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that clarifies everything. Thank you!